# Custom field tag in devise registration view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to add custom field tag in `devise registration view` but that field doesn't exist in `users` table. I just want user select some value in that field  and i get information about selected  value in `params` at the time of sign up. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

```
Devise_registration_view:

<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type, 'Role' %>
    <%= f.select :type, %w{Admin Teacher Student Guardian}, :prompt => 'Select', required: true, placeholder: 'Roles' %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use attr_accessor for User model which will help you to get and set value for attribute which is not there in table, Please refer this link. [attr_accessor_details](https://ledtechnica.com/rails-attr-accessor-validations-and-devise-f89869a2c00d)

updating answer for adding custom validation for attribute created by attr_accessor

```
attr_accessor :test_attribute
validate :check_test_attribute
def check_test_attribute
  errors.add(:test_attribute, "is missing") if test_attribute.blank?
end
```

Comment: can i also add validations for attr_accessor in model?

Comment: Yes you can add custom validations @vishal-goel